# selenium doesn't allow modifying httpheaders to add things like csrf token in django forms based on ajax

Tags: django, testing, selenium

I'm using selenium for my automated browser testing but it is failing while testing the login process. the reason being the way I'm sending my csrf token in the requestHeader instead of sending it with the form which I found a sandard way to deal with ajax based forms. [here](http://brack3t.com/ajax-and-django-views.html)

I found one way around this problem by using proxy to inject additional headers to the requests generated by the browser. But I'm looking for better options if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you're using Selenium WebDriver instead of old Senelnium RC.

Selenium WebDriver is just automated user using the browser.

You should need nothing custom to make it work. Just be sure jQuery finished setting up everything and the browser should send the custom header along with request.